# Not found as file or resource

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, itext, xamarin.uwp, pdf-reader

I am adding text to existing pdf using Itextsharp in xamarin forms UWP. For this I am reading the source file using PdfReader like

```
string source = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Test.pdf");
string target = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Test_1.pdf");
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source);
```

when ever PdfReader read's the file it is showing exception like

> C:\Users\ ...\Documents\Test.pdf not found as file or resource.

Please help me for how to read the file using PdfReader.

Comment: does the test file exist in the Documents folder?

Comment: @jason yes it exist's.